# Passing Session variables suddenly stopped working

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

I have a handful of websites that access MySQL databases on Hostmonster.  This morning the logins stopped working.  The logins are all still correct - they work in Navicat and other environments.  Hosting Support says nothing was changed on their end.  It's important to note that none of the coding was changed before it stopped working and this is occurring on multiple domains/websites.

Preliminary testing SEEMS to indicate to me that the session variables established in the login process aren't being passed on somehow, but maybe I'm wrong.  Here's the code from the second page after the login.  The switch suddenly doesn't work and instead of redirecting the browser, it stays on this page.  First time posting, so please forgive any newbie errors in how to post the question.

```
<?php 
if(!session_id()) session_start(); 
switch($_SESSION['access']) { 
case "1": 
    header("Location: contestant-account.php"); 
    break; 
case "2": 
    header("Location: coach-account.php"); 
    break; 
case "3": 
    header("Location: coach-account.php"); 
    break; 
case "4": 
    header("Location: coach-account.php"); 
    break; 
} ?>
```

Code of login page...

```
    <?php
@session_start();
?>
<?php require_once('Connections/myisateam.php'); ?>
<?php require_once("webassist/form_validations/wavt_scripts_php.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("webassist/form_validations/wavt_validatedform_php.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("webassist/security_assist/helper_php.php" ); ?>
<?php
if ((isset($_POST["LogIn_submit"])&&(!isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Remember_my_information"])) && $_POST["LogIn_submit"] != "")) {
    setcookie("RememberMePWD", "", time()+(60*60*24*30), "/", "", 0);
}
?>
<?php
if ((isset($_POST["LogIn_submit"])&&(!isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Remember_my_information"])) && $_POST["LogIn_submit"] != "")) {
    setcookie("RememberMeUN", "", time()+(60*60*24*30), "/", "", 0);
}
?>
<?php
if ((isset($_POST["LogIn_submit"])&&(isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Remember_my_information"])) && $_POST["Log_In_group_Remember_my_information"] != "")) {
    setcookie("RememberMePWD", "".((isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Password"]))?$_POST["Log_In_group_Password"]:"")  ."", time()+(60*60*24*30), "/", "", 0);
}
?>
<?php
if ((isset($_POST["LogIn_submit"])&&(isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Remember_my_information"])) && $_POST["Log_In_group_Remember_my_information"] != "")) {
    setcookie("RememberMeUN", "".((isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Email_Address"]))?$_POST["Log_In_group_Email_Address"]:"")  ."", time()+(60*60*24*30), "/", "", 0);
}
?>
<?php
if ((isset($_POST["LogIn_submit"])&&(!isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Log_me_in_automatically"])) && $_POST["LogIn_submit"] != "")) {
    setcookie("AutoLoginPWD", "", time()+(60*60*24*30), "/", "", 0);
}
?>
<?php
if ((isset($_POST["LogIn_submit"])&&(!isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Log_me_in_automatically"])) && $_POST["LogIn_submit"] != "")) {
    setcookie("AutoLoginUN", "", time()+(60*60*24*30), "/", "", 0);
}
?>
<?php
if ((isset($_POST["LogIn_submit"])&&(isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Log_me_in_automatically"])) && $_POST["Log_In_group_Log_me_in_automatically"] != "")) {
    setcookie("AutoLoginPWD", "".((isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Password"]))?$_POST["Log_In_group_Password"]:"")  ."", time()+(60*60*24*30), "/", "", 0);
}
?>
<?php
if ((isset($_POST["LogIn_submit"])&&(isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Log_me_in_automatically"])) && $_POST["Log_In_group_Log_me_in_automatically"] != "")) {
    setcookie("AutoLoginUN", "".((isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Email_Address"]))?$_POST["Log_In_group_Email_Address"]:"")  ."", time()+(60*60*24*30), "/", "", 0);
}
?>
<?php
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $WA_Auth_Parameter = array(
    "connection" => $myisateam,
    "database" => $database_myisateam,
    "tableName" => "members",
    "columns" => explode($WA_Auth_Separator,"email".$WA_Auth_Separator."password"),
    "columnValues" => explode($WA_Auth_Separator,"".((isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Email_Address"]))?$_POST["Log_In_group_Email_Address"]:"")  ."".$WA_Auth_Separator."".((isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Password"]))?$_POST["Log_In_group_Password"]:"")  .""),
    "columnTypes" => explode($WA_Auth_Separator,"text".$WA_Auth_Separator."text"),
    "sessionColumns" => explode($WA_Auth_Separator,"member_id".$WA_Auth_Separator."access".$WA_Auth_Separator."firstname".$WA_Auth_Separator."lastname".$WA_Auth_Separator."email".$WA_Auth_Separator."group_id"),
    "sessionNames" => explode($WA_Auth_Separator,"SecurityAssist_member_id".$WA_Auth_Separator."access".$WA_Auth_Separator."firstname".$WA_Auth_Separator."lastname".$WA_Auth_Separator."email".$WA_Auth_Separator."group_id"),
    "successRedirect" => "redirect.php",
    "failRedirect" => "login.php?failedLogin=1",
    "gotoPreviousURL" => TRUE,
    "keepQueryString" => TRUE
    );

    WA_AuthenticateUser($WA_Auth_Parameter);
}
?>
<?php
if((((isset($_SESSION["SecurityAssist_member_id"]) && $_SESSION["SecurityAssist_member_id"] != "")?"LoggedIn":"") == "")&&(((isset($_COOKIE["AutoLoginUN"]))?$_COOKIE["AutoLoginUN"]:"") != "")&&(((isset($_COOKIE["AutoLoginPWD"]))?$_COOKIE["AutoLoginPWD"]:"") != "")){
    $WA_Auth_Parameter = array(
    "connection" => $myisateam,
    "database" => $database_myisateam,
    "tableName" => "members",
    "columns" => explode($WA_Auth_Separator,"email".$WA_Auth_Separator."password"),
    "columnValues" => explode($WA_Auth_Separator,"".((isset($_COOKIE["AutoLoginUN"]))?$_COOKIE["AutoLoginUN"]:"")  ."".$WA_Auth_Separator."".((isset($_COOKIE["AutoLoginPWD"]))?$_COOKIE["AutoLoginPWD"]:"")  .""),
    "columnTypes" => explode($WA_Auth_Separator,"text".$WA_Auth_Separator."text"),
    "sessionColumns" => explode($WA_Auth_Separator,"member_id".$WA_Auth_Separator."access"),
    "sessionNames" => explode($WA_Auth_Separator,"SecurityAssist_member_id".$WA_Auth_Separator."access"),
    "successRedirect" => "coach-account.php",
    "failRedirect" => "",
    "gotoPreviousURL" => TRUE,
    "keepQueryString" => TRUE
    );

    WA_AuthenticateUser($WA_Auth_Parameter);
}
?>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["LogIn_submit"]))  {
  $WAFV_Redirect = "".(htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES))  ."?invalid=true";
  $_SESSION['WAVT_login_Errors'] = "";
  if ($WAFV_Redirect == "")  {
    $WAFV_Redirect = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
  }
  $WAFV_Errors = "";
  $WAFV_Errors .= WAValidateRQ((isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Email_Address"])?$_POST["Log_In_group_Email_Address"]:"") . "",true,1);
  $WAFV_Errors .= WAValidateRQ((isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Password"])?$_POST["Log_In_group_Password"]:"") . "",true,2);
  $WAFV_Errors .= WAValidateEL((isset($_POST["Log_In_group_Password"])?$_POST["Log_In_group_Password"]:"") . "",6,500,true,3);

  if ($WAFV_Errors != "")  {
    PostResult($WAFV_Redirect,$WAFV_Errors,"login");
  }
}
?>
```

Error logs from server...

```
[15-Dec-2016 22:29:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): write failed: No space left on device (28) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[15-Dec-2016 22:29:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[15-Dec-2016 22:29:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): write failed: No space left on device (28) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[15-Dec-2016 22:29:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[15-Dec-2016 22:29:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0
[15-Dec-2016 22:29:38 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[15-Dec-2016 23:05:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): write failed: No space left on device (28) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[15-Dec-2016 23:05:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[15-Dec-2016 23:05:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): write failed: No space left on device (28) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[15-Dec-2016 23:05:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[15-Dec-2016 23:05:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0
[15-Dec-2016 23:05:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[15-Dec-2016 23:36:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0
[15-Dec-2016 23:36:22 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[15-Dec-2016 23:48:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): write failed: No space left on device (28) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[15-Dec-2016 23:48:24 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[15-Dec-2016 23:48:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0
[15-Dec-2016 23:48:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[16-Dec-2016 00:32:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0
[16-Dec-2016 00:32:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[16-Dec-2016 00:42:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0
[16-Dec-2016 00:42:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[16-Dec-2016 00:42:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): write failed: No space left on device (28) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[16-Dec-2016 00:42:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[16-Dec-2016 00:42:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): write failed: No space left on device (28) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[16-Dec-2016 00:42:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in /home3/fresnobo/public_html/bootcampadmin/includes/common/KT_functions.inc.php on line 461
[16-Dec-2016 00:42:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0
[16-Dec-2016 00:42:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
[16-Dec-2016 00:43:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0
[16-Dec-2016 00:43:03 UTC] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: That if seems superfluous, just call `session_start()`

Comment: Agreed - thanks.  Tried it - no joy.

Comment: You should check, as debugging, the return value on every page load - just dump it out. If your session storage is full or inaccessible, sessions just won't work - this is a reasonably common problem - for instance a disk where file based sessions are being stored might have become full.

Comment: You did inspect $_SESSION?

Comment: Ryan, code is as expected, and comes from server.  Thanks.

Comment: @Progrock how do I do that?  :/

Comment: I'd probably suggest a diagnostic page under a hard to guess URL, that has `<?php session_start(); var_dump($_SESSION);`.

Comment: that @session_start() also kills any error logging.

Comment: Thanks @progrock.  comes back array(0) { }

Comment: Create another script where you assign something to the session `<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';`.  Then visit the dump page to see if values are carrying. Also have you checked your web server's error log?

Comment: @progrock thank you for your patience.  

I checked server error logs (hadn't done that in a while) and see errors for one of the domains in question that seem to indicate something is full and session data isn't being written.  I'll paste logs into original post.

Comment: Are you able to see if that's the issue?  That may be what @pvg was referring to.

Comment: Yes it says right there - the disk you're using for session store is full so obviously, sessions don't work. Make some space.

Comment: Thanks... first time this occurred. I appreciate it.

Comment: Guess it's just confusing as these sites are on a shared hosting environment and I'm not at my capacity on the server.  So is it just a particular directory like /tmp that reaches capacity?

Comment: Depends how PHP is configured. There's also typically a periodically invoked process that cleans up old session data. Check your config, yell at your provider.

Comment: Finally got it fixed - customer service took 45 minutes to find and fix - wish the previous tech would have thought of that.  Thanks to all who helped me get it solved.

Comment: @KareyNickel glad you got it sorted out! Now stop using shared hosting :)